# What happens in CALL when gas is set to 0?

Tags: evm, opcode

Reading the documentation on the CALL opcode :

"call contract at address a with input mem[in..(in+insize)) providing g gas and v wei and output area mem[out..(out+outsize)) returning 0 on error (eg. out of gas) and 1 on success"

Where CALL is

call(g, a, v, in, insize, out, outsize)

If I test a contract which uses the transfer function and then check what happens in assembly, I see that the stack does indeed represent the right address `a` at the first position of the stack and the right value `v` at the second position of the stack. However, the 0th postion of the stack is set to 0. This would mean 0 gas is sent with this call. In transfer, 2300 gas has to be sent, but this apparently does not happen.

How does this work?

EDIT Contract code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract Transfer{
function test() public payable {msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);}
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code or the specific transaction, please? You are right that it isn't supposed to be that way.

Comment: I am just trying to `address(something).call.value(somewei)`. I wanted to see how this code looked like in assembly hence why it does it like that. But this thus spawns 0x0 as gas argument on EVM.

Comment: What instructions are executed directly before the `CALL`? I just tried it and my compiler puts the `GAS` instruction right before the `CALL`, so the value on top of the stack is the whole remaining gas when the execution reaches the call.

Comment: Oh wait I'm stupid. I meant to actually call transfer. You are right when you call normally it forwards all current gas. I will add contract code.

Comment: Hm, it still has a non-zero value on top of the stack for me. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/TbJZQrG.png) of the debugger.

Comment: I tried to make an extensive answer here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70208/gas-is-0-when-executing-call-opcode/78162#78162

Answer (score 1):

That is highly unlikely... With Solidity 0.4.25, compiling `address.call()` would give you:

```
...
gas
call
```

As you can see, the last parameter pushed on the stack is the total amount of available amount of gas *after* the execution of the GAS opcode itself.

However, in your example, you are compiling `address.transfer()`, which, per the Solidity docs, forwards a standard gas stipend of 2300.

```
  0x8fc
  ...
  dup9  // duplicates 0x8fc=2300
  call
```

Comment: EVM CALL acts like Solidity send.