# is OPCODE applicable for sending ethers from wallet to another account?

Tags: gas, evm, gas-price, opcode

I know smart contracts are converted to bytecodes and they are executing OPCODES in the EVM. But I want to know, what OPCODES does Wallet to wallet transactions have?

Answer (score 1):

OPCODES are also known as hexadecimal instructions that are mapped to human readable format.

There are number of EVM OPCODES available to use. You can even write an whole smart contract by using solidity in-line assembly. Which is hard to read and write but you can save alot of gas.

So anyways, I am sure you are familiar with it, the OPCODE to transfer ETH from wallet to another wallet is known as [CALL](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/opcodes/#:%7E:text=F1-,CALL,-AA).

Yes, people refer CALL, DELEGATECALL, and STATICCALL to low level function. But, in fact, they are one of few OPCODES EVM supports.

Link to solidity in-assembly [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/assembly.html).

You can read more about the call [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70208/gas-is-0-when-executing-call-opcode).

You can read more about call vs transfer vs send [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-transfer-vs-send-vs-call-function-64c92cfc878a#:%7E:text=call%7Bvalue%3A%20msg.,sent%20in%20the%20data%20variable.).

Tell me if it helps!